# MySQLX.GetSession exception: : 'Expected message id: 2. Received message id: 10'

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to connect to my database via MySQL DevAPI using following code:

```
 var connectionString = string.Format("server={0};port={1};user={2};password={3};", host, port, username, password);
 _session = MySQLX.GetSession(connectionString);
 Schema = _session.GetSchema(database);
```

However I am seeing this error message:

> "MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Expected message id: 2. 
>   Received message id: 10'"

I have no idea what this means and googling doesn't produce any results.
My connection string is correct, because I can connect using simple `Connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);` syntax.

I've been following [this example](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/x-devapi-userguide/en/database-connection-example.html) to get started with DevAPI.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I figured it out, my table in database had id field of type BIGINT which looks like is not supported and INT was expected.